# tableAdapter and related rows

Tags: c#, sql-server, tableadapter

I have a one-to-many relationship between users and messages.

I have the following query in my message adapter:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.message
JOIN dbo.[user] ON dbo.[user].Id = dbo.message.user_id
JOIN dbo.[color] ON dbo.[user].color_id = dbo.[color].Id
WHERE dbo.message.Id > @id
ORDER BY dbo.message.Id ASC
```

Now how can I refer to the user of a message via table adapter?

When I do something like this:

```
MessageBox.Show(messageRow.userRow.username);
```

I receive a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: check null . `if(messageRow!=null && messageRow.userRow!=null){ MessageBox.Show(messageRow.userRow.username); }`

Comment: How does it solve the problem? I want to see the username, not skip it

Comment: what is your query result?

Comment: I don't understand the question here. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I simply want to display username of the user who wrote the message but the code I attached above throws the exception. Why is it throwing the exception instead of displaying the username?